# Bring in query tables as separate parts

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to bringing a csv file into Excel. The original way is to use query tables. Is there a way to skip a column while adding it?

Right now, I am using `QueryTables.Add` directly.

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;\\some_place\some_file.csv", Destination:=Range("A4"))
                .Name = "Some_Name"
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileStartRow = 2
                .AdjustColumnWidth = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

This will bring the whole **some_file.csv** to "A4", but let's say I want to break it up as column A to column E, skip column F, and then column G to column Z. Is there some way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd honestly use Power Query to only import certain columns.

Comment: Use Power Query / "Get & Transform" for this.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is there something like SELECT ALL or I should list the names explicitly? Sorry, new to Power Query.

Comment: import the file via powerquery then when the query editor pops up you right click remove the column you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ADODB Connection to import data from your CSV files with SQL Select query. Following is the sample code for your reference:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
Dim con As Object, rs As Object
Dim FolderPath As String, ConStr As String, Query As String

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Query = "Select A, C, D from test.csv"  ' use column names and original csv file name
FolderPath = "C:\Users\User1\Documents\"
ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FolderPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)"";Persist Security Info=False"
con.Open ConStr
rs.Open Query, con

Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

con.Close
Set con = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```